# Is there any difference between "I still work" and "I'm still working"?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *I still work* and *I'm still working*? For example:

> Person A: Hey, I haven't seen you in ages. What's new with you?
>
> Person B: Same old. **I still work**/**I'm still working** at the company.

Generally I'm aware of the difference between the present simple and present continuous, but in the given context I can't see any.

Comment: If you know the difference, you can apply that here. One is a general statement and the other applies to right now.  Two ways to say the same thing.

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+still+work+there%2CI%27m+still+working+there&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) comparing ***I still work there*** and ***I'm still working there***. Which used to be about equally common, but in recent decades Simple Present ***work*** has started to become far more likely. ***But*** I suggest that if A and B were both "of a certain age", and A had said something like ***I  retired a couple of years ago. How about you**?*, B would be *much* more likely to reply ***I'm still working***, not ***I still work***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are talking about your continued employment at a company, or just the fact that you aren't retired, then both phrases mean the same.

If you are talking about a task you are engaged in at the moment, then "I am still working." is idiomatic.
But in that context, "I still work." isn't idiomatic.